# Don't queryset records get ids when saved?

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Rails, and in symfony with Doctrine, you can save a record and then you'll have the record's id. For example:

```
b = Bank.new
b.save
#b.id now has a value
```

But in Django that's apparently not how it works:

```
>>> b = Bank()
>>> b.name = "Fred's Bank"
>>> b.identifier = "fred"
>>> b.save()
>>> b.id
>>> b.id.__class__
<type 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

As you can see, `b.id` evaluates to nothing. Do I have to go back and select the id if I want it? That would be a pain in the ass, especially for tables that have a lot of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *is* how it works in Django. Assuming that `Bank` is a Django model, it does get an ID on save, and the current instance reflects that. I can't imagine what you have done to break that. You'll need to post the code of the Bank model.

Comment: Okay, so to clarify, `b.id` should be showing me the id of that saved record? If that's the case, that's all I need to know. I have some ideas about where I could have broken it.